# Vue3 Reactive value is not updating as expected

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have this .ts file:

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'

export const TitleComponent = () => {
  const obj = reactive({
    title: "This should be reactive"
  }) 

  const updateObj = () => {
    obj.title = 'This is now different'
  }
  return {...toRefs(obj), updateObj }

}
```

I then import is into a vue component which DISPLAYS it

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { TitleComponent } from 'some/place'

export default defineComponent({
  const { title } = TitleComponent()
  return { title }
})
```

Then, I use the function `updateObj` in another component that runs that method. But it doesn't update the title value. What gives?

```
<template>
  <button @click="updateObj">Click Me</button>
</template>

import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { TitleComponent } from 'some/place'

export default defineComponent({
  const { updateObj } = TitleComponent()
  return { updateObj}
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `obj` outside of `export const TitleComponent = () => {}`.

```js
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue';

const obj = reactive({
  title: 'This should be reactive'
});

export const TitleComponent = () => {
  const updateObj = () => {
    obj.title = 'This is now different'
  };

  return { ...toRefs(obj), updateObj };
}
```

When its inside and you import/call `TitleComponent()` it creates a new instance of `obj` every time.

Comment: although this is working, it isn't updating the UI... 

If you console log the value it changes, but not what you see in the HTML

Comment: @RizaKhan I just reproduced it in codesandbox.io and it updates. Only difference being I wrapped what you have inside of `defineComponent({})` in a `setup() {}`.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to this codesandbox?

Comment: @RizaKhan https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-goldwasser-iow8k