# To-dos don't update when I choose a to-do list

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have two components: `TodoList` and `TodoListsList`. They get their data from states in `todos.js` and `todoLists.js` modules accordingly. When I choose some to-do list, i.e mark it as active, `TodoListsList` is updated, but `TodoLists` isn't, thought the data is updated. Here's how I do it.

`todoListsState` and `markAsActive()` (todoLists.js):

```js
import todos from '@/modules/todos.js'

// ... some code ...

const todoListsState = reactive({
    todoLists: [],
    todoListsAreLoading: false,
    removedTodoListId: null,
    editedTodoListId: null,
    editedTodoListName: '',
    baseTodoListsApiUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_TODO_LISTS_API_URL,
    todoListCreationFormModalId: 'todoListCreationFormModal',
    todoListNameChangeFormModalId: 'todoListNameChangeFormModal'
});

// ... some code ...

function markAsActive(value) {
    let { close } = infoToast();
    if (value) {
        axios.post((todoListsState.baseTodoListsApiUrl + 'mark-as-active'), {
            activatedTodoListId: value
        }).then(function () {
            getTodoLists();
            const { getTodos } = todos();
            getTodos();
        }).catch(function () {
            dangerToast('Failed to mark to-do list as active.');
        }).finally(() => {
            close();
        });
    }
}
```

`todosState` and `getTodos()` (`todos.js`):

```js
const todosState = reactive({
    todos: [],
    activeTodoListId: 0,
    removedTodoId: null,
    editedTodoId: null,
    editedTodoText: '',
    todosAreLoading: false,
    baseTodosApiUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_TODOS_API_URL,
    todoAdditionFormModalId: 'todoAdditionFormModal',
    todoEditFormModalId: 'todoEditFormModal'
});

// ... some code ...

async function getTodos() {
    try {
        todosState.todosAreLoading = true;
        const response = await axios.get(todosState.baseTodosApiUrl);
        todosState.activeTodoListId = response.data[0];
        todosState.todos = response.data[1];
    } catch (e) {
        dangerToast('To-dos loading failed.');
    } finally {
        todosState.todosAreLoading = false;
    }
}
```

How does `todosState.todos` look in console:
[image]

`todosState.todos` when `Todos.vue` is mounted:
[image]

It doesn't look like the array looses it's reactivity.

If you need something else to understand my question, feel free to ask. Help appreciated.

Comment: take a look at [deep-watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) documentation, so when the data is changed you can detect and update the component.

Comment: mo3n, I'll try it out, and then we'll continue. Thanks for advice!

Comment: mo3n, the problem is not in the component. I've also tried to watch the state change in the grandparent component named Todos.vue (which also is a router view), where it is provided (I use provide/inject). It isn't updated there. But getTodos() is called and todosState.todos is different in console. You can also try my app out. I'll give you some links. Vue 3 app: https://github.com/loglinn05/todos. Laravel API for this app: https://github.com/loglinn05/todos-api.

Comment: mo3n, I have also watched todosState.todos in todos.js and todoLists.js. It updates in both of them.

Comment: mo3n, I have solved this problem already. Also, thank you for devoting your precious time! Good luck and all the best to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved! I have just moved `todosState` out of

```js
export default function () {}
```

and it works! Finally! [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996958/vue3-reactive-value-is-not-updating-as-expected) helped me a lot.